# Upgrading to Gnome 3.12 in Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, upgrade, gnome

**Hello my friends. Recently Gnome 3.12 was released as an update for gnome users. so I decided to upgrade to the newest version as explained [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-gnome-312-in-fedora-20.html).
After step 1, I tried to update Fedora using Yumex, But I got this error:**

---

Dependency Resolution Errors:

Package: 1:NetworkManager-bt-0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
    Requires: NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20
    Removing: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-33.git20131003.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.0-33.git20131003.fc20
    Obsoleted By: 1:NetworkManager-adsl-0.9.9.1-4.git20140319.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        Not found
    Updated By: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-4.git20140319.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-4.git20140319.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-20.git20131003.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.0-20.git20131003.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-0.git20140228.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-0.git20140228.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-1.git20140310.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-1.git20140310.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-2.git20140314.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-2.git20140314.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20Package: ekiga-4.0.1-6.fc20.x86_64 (@fedora)
    Requires: libcamel-1.2.so.45()(64bit)
    Removing: evolution-data-server-3.10.4-3.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
        libcamel-1.2.so.45()(64bit)
    Updated By: evolution-data-server-3.12.0-1.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
       ~libcamel-1.2.so.49()(64bit)
    Available: evolution-data-server-3.10.2-2.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
        libcamel-1.2.so.45()(64bit)
    Available: evolution-data-server-3.11.90-1.fc20.i686 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-i386)
        Not found
    Available: evolution-data-server-3.11.91-1.fc20.i686 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-i386)
        Not found
    Available: evolution-data-server-3.11.92-1.fc20.i686 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-i386)
        Not foundPackage: nm-connection-editor-0.9.9.0-9.git20140123.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
    Requires: libgnome-bluetooth.so.12()(64bit)
    Removing: 1:gnome-bluetooth-libs-3.10.0-1.fc20.x86_64 (@anaconda)
        libgnome-bluetooth.so.12()(64bit)
    Updated By: 1:gnome-bluetooth-libs-3.12.0-1.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
       ~libgnome-bluetooth.so.13()(64bit)Package: 1:NetworkManager-atm-0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
    Requires: NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20
    Removing: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-33.git20131003.fc20.x86_64 (@updates)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.0-33.git20131003.fc20
    Obsoleted By: 1:NetworkManager-adsl-0.9.9.1-4.git20140319.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        Not found
    Updated By: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-4.git20140319.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-4.git20140319.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.0-20.git20131003.fc20.x86_64 (fedora)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.0-20.git20131003.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-0.git20140228.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-0.git20140228.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-1.git20140310.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-1.git20140310.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-2.git20140314.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-2.git20140314.fc20
    Available: 1:NetworkManager-0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20.x86_64 (rhughes-f20-gnome-3-12-x86_64)
        NetworkManager(x86-64) = 1:0.9.9.1-3.git20140317.fc20

Comment: I'd suggest following the instructions from the [Fedora Magazine](http://fedoramagazine.org/running-gnome-3-12-on-fedora-20/) and report any issues to the author (packager) i.e. [Richard Hughes](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User:Rhughes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support.
At first, I entered this to enable gdm.service:

> ## systemctl enable gdm.service

Then, I restarted it using this:

> ## systecmtl restart gdm.service

Thanks to IL Mostro because of the codes and great instructions!